# Probability of a bottling machine overflowing when it gets filled up with parameters $\mu = 1000$ and $\sigma^2 = 100$ given

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

The content of a certain type of paint can is stated on the label as $1000$g of paint.
However, the bottling machine cannot fill this quantity exactly.

Therefore, the actually filled quantity (in grams) is normally distributed with the parameters $\mu = 1000$ and $\sigma^2  = 100$. The cans which were used, can hold a maximum of $1020$ g of paint.

**How can one find out the probability, that the can overflows when it gets filled up?**
It says that we should first use an appropriate scaling and standardization to get a standard normally distributed random variable.

I know that for a standard normally distributed random variable $X$ ~ $N(0,1)$ the following holds:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
x& 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.5 & 1 & 2 & 5 \\ \hline
F_x(x) & 0.540 & 0.579 & 0.691 & 0.841 & 0.977 & 1.000\\ \hline
\end{array}

On a [PDF](https://www-zeuthen.desy.de/%7Ekolanosk/smd_ss02/skripte/vert2.pdf) on the internet I found out that, the transition to distributions $N(\sigma, \mu)$ can be found through scaling $x$ with $\sigma$ and shifting it by $\mu$:

$$x = \frac{x' - \mu}{\sigma}$$

Regarding standardization it says that the following integral should be used:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ax^2}dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} $$

The problem is, that I don't know in which way I have to apply the formula(s) to get the probability. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this help? https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalDistribution.html

Comment: Note as you are finding probability of the paint overflowing, the lower bound of $x$ for the integral should be $1020$. The other way is to look up Z-table. You may want to read more about it on internet. Here is a link I could find - https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-normal-distribution.html

Comment: @MathLover Thank you, but what is my $a$ there and the upper bound for the integral? And which value for x do I have to use from the table?

Comment: There is no $a$ in the integral. Can you pls clarify? Upper bound is of course $\infty$

Comment: @MathLover Which integral are you referring to? The one in the post? How can I calculate it if the upper bound is $\infty$?

Comment: The first link that I shared. Please refer to that. You have everything you need for the integral.

Comment: @MathLover Mind referencing the line of the function provided in mathworld?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126774/discussion-between-math-lover-and-user10930711).

Comment: You have $X\sim\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100,\sigma=10).$ You seek $P(X > 1020) = P\left(Z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} = \frac{1020-1000}{10}=2\right),$ where $Z$ is standard normal. Finish it to get as near as you can to  $0.02275013$ (exact value from R), using standard normal tables. // Can you figure out what $\sigma$ would have to be in order to decrease the probability to $0.01?$

Comment: @BruceET Yes, I already got the answer. Thank you for the help :)